# How to get youtube video description with pytube

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytube

When I try to get youtube video description with this code:

```
from pytube import YouTube
video = YouTube("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N9bLO0XY3zs&ab_channel=CompanyEggs")
print (video.description())
```

I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/mmthe/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/main.py", line 24, in <module>
    print (video.description())
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pytube gives you an object and you just need to print / access attributes of that object.

```py
from pytube import YouTube

video = YouTube("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N9bLO0XY3zs&ab_channel=CompanyEggs")
print (video.description)
```

gives

```
Just drink another one


Song: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ag1o3koTLWM
```

Comment: [BUG] Youtube.description is None https://github.com/pytube/pytube/issues/1626